# error : cubeMaterial is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a problem with javascript .
it shows me the error that I wrote in the title to the line:

> this.color = cubeMaterial.color.getHex();

I can not understand where I'm wrong. I am beginner.

I tried to declare the variable "var cubeMaterial;" outside function "createCube" but it gives the error " Can not read property ' color' of undefined " Thanks!

```
    var scene,camera,renderer;

    function createScene() {
    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects,cameras and lights.

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //screate a camera, which defines where we're looking at

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    //position and point the camera to the center of the scene

    camera.position.x=-30;
    camera.position.y=40;
    camera.position.z=30;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    // create a render and set the size

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEcE));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    //add the output of the renderer to the html element

     document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
     }

    var ambientLight,spotLight;

    function createLights(){
    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);

    //add spotlight for the shadow

    spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(-40,60,-10);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    scene.add(spotLight);
    }

    var cube,sphere,plane;

    function createPlane(){
    // create a plane

    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,40,11);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0Xcccccc });
    plane= new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

    //rotate and position the plane

    plane.rotation.x= -0.5*Math.PI;
    plane.position.x= 15;
    plane.position.y= 0;
    plane.position.z=0;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;

    //add the plane to the scene

    scene.add(plane);
    }

   function createCube(){
   //create a cube

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00,                  transparent:true} );
    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );

    //position the cube

    cube.position.x = -4;
    cube.position.y = 3;
    cube.position.z =0;
    cube.castShadow= true;

    //add cube to the scene

    cube.name = "cube"
    scene.add(cube);

    }

    function createSphere(){
    //create a sphere

    var sphereGeometry= new THREE.SphereGeometry(4,20,20);
    var sphereMaterial= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x7777ff});
    sphere= new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry,sphereMaterial);

    //position the sphere

    sphere.position.x=20;
    sphere.position.y=0;
    sphere.position.z=2;
    sphere.castShadow = true;

    //add the sphere ti the scene

    scene.add(sphere);
    }


     var controls = new function() {

        this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
        this.bouncingSpeed = 0.03;
        this.opacity= 0.6;
        this.color = cubeMaterial.color.getHex();
        }

       function addControlGui(controlObject){

        var gui = new dat.GUI();
        gui.add(controlObject, 'rotationSpeed',0,0.5);
        gui.add(controlObject, 'bouncingSpeed',0,0.5);
        gui.add(controlObject,"opacity", 0.1, 1 );
        gui.add(controlObject,"color");

        }

         var step = 0;

        function render(){
      //rotate the cube aroun its axes

     cube.rotation.x += controls.rotationSpeed;
    cube.rotation.y += controls.rotationSpeed;
    cube.rotation.z += controls.rotationSpeed;

    scene.getObjectByName("cube").material.opacity= controls.opacity;
    scene.getObjectByName("cube").material.color = new   THREE.Color(controls.color);

    //bounce the sphere up and down

    step+=controls.bouncingSpeed;
    sphere.position.x= 20+(10*(Math.cos(step+=0.01)));
    sphere.position.y = 2 +( 10*Math.abs(Math.sin(step+=0.03)));

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);

    //render using requestAnimationFrame
     }


    function init(){

    createScene();

    createLights();

    createPlane();

    createCube();

    createSphere();

    addControlGui(controls); 

    render();
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope problem! When you declare cubeMaterial inside the createSphere function, it will only exist inside that function.

Variables declared at the top of the code, outside of the functions, such as on the line `var scene,camera,renderer;` will exist in all the inner functions.

Does that make sense? So all you have to do is make sure you declare the cubeMaterial in the right scope. Try putting it at the top next to the scene declaration.

Comment: I tried but it does not work . It gives me the error " Cannot read property 'color' of undefined".

Comment: Your other problem is that the controls function is running before anything else is. Remove the "new" keyword there, so it becomes `var controls = function() {`

Comment: Done!  but dat.GUI library gives me this error ` Uncaught Error: Object function () {
            
            this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
            this.bouncingSpeed = 0.03;
            this.opacity= 0.6;
            this.color = cubeMaterial.color.getHex();
        } has no property "rotationSpeed"`

Comment: Make sure you're following the correct way to use dat.GUI, like in this example: https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#4--Color-Controllers

So instead of `addControlGui(controls); ` it would be:

`var controlObj = new controls();
    addControlGui(controlObj);`

Comment: I added more information, but the problem there is still.

Comment: I have tried to change it as you told me to do, but it gave me the error "controls not defined . " So I rewrote the code and so the controls work but the cube and the sphere disappeared from the scene. The consol does not show me any error.

Comment: You should post the new code. Or better yet, upload a working example on something like http://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/. It'll make it a lot easier to fix/test/show you what's wrong!